# Time Spent by user on a web page + Iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to measure the time spent by a user on web pages. It's doesn't include the time when a user navigates away from the browser.

I found few open source libraries like [Timejs](https://github.com/jasonzissman/TimeMe.js/) library which can measure the time spent by a user on a web page, but when a user is watching a Youtube video on the page, these libraries don't measure that time.

.

1. Is there a way to handle this case or any other library which handles this case?
2. Actually, these libraries fail to calculate the time spent by the user inside an iFrame.What is the best way to know when a user is active in an IFrame?
3. How does Google/AppNexus/Motomo calculate interaction time? Is there a common design/architecture that they follow?

PS: I am trying to integrate the library with my react App. If there exists any similar method to solve this problem in React. Please let me know in comments/answers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This could be related to media events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: Hi Deepak. I am the author of timeme.js. I still have not solved this problem. Please let me know if you find a solution!

For reference - when viewing a web page, the window object emits the same event (blur) when you switch tabs AND when you focus on an embedded iFrame. This makes it very hard to distinguish the two. The only solution I can think of is to use a timing library inside of the iFrame, but that requires you to have control of that code. We unfortunately cannot modify Youtube :)

Comment: Sure @jason.zissman I'm working on it. Will update here.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 Page Visibility API is the answer of your question.

You need to just listen an event as per the browser and it will be triggered every time when user will jump to another tab.

Look to [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)

Comment: If I'm working on a tab and I leave my machine as is. Page Visibility API assumes it as an active page(But the page is inactive). I want to stop my time in such a case.

Comment: API works only when you switch to some other window or tab. You can club previous approach with it to find exact time.

Comment: I tried it but failed to do so. I'd be more than happy you can help me more on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good and security way to do it but you need webSocket implementation.
  Make special socket client and server for this feature.

When you client is disconnected you can count that your user is not anymore on page. Implement timer's for time log on server part.

Page Visibility API look like solution for local calculation(unprotected). If you work with money or some kind of value's better use server for validation.

p.s.

If you have a buggy situation with timer ( on inactive tab ) then use HackerTimer library (combination with web workers).

Answer (score 0):

Just start a timer when the user enters the page (lots of ways to do this) To pause and continue the timer, try using the onunload() and unload() events (they may not work exactly as you want it to, but it is the best thing I could find. Take a look at this to help you https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp
Hope this helps!